# Calling js function on button click isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Any reason why this isn't running when clicked? I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<button id="button-container-like" onclick="rate($(this).attr(\'id\'))"><span class="thumbs-up"></span>Like</button>

<script>
function rate(rating){
var data = 'rating='+rating+'&id=<?php echo $eventId; ?>&userid56=<?PHP echo $userid55; ?>';

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'includes/rate.php', //POSTS FORM TO THIS FILE
   data: data,
   success: function(e){
   $(".ratings").html(e); //REPLACES THE TEXT OF view.php
}
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: well, are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

```
<button id="button-container-like" ><span class="thumbs-up"></span>Like</button>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $("#button-container-like").click(function() {
            rate($(this).attr("id"));
        });

        function rate(rating) {
            var data = 'rating=' + rating + '&id=<?php echo $eventId; ?>&userid56=<?PHP echo $userid55; ?>';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'includes/rate.php', //POSTS FORM TO THIS FILE
                data: data,
                success: function(e) {
                    $(".ratings").html(e); //REPLACES THE TEXT OF view.php
                }
            });
        }
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing else going on in this code, then remove the slashes from your `onclick` code.  They are unnecessary and cause an error.

`onclick="rate($(this).attr('id'))"`

Comment: Or use the simpler `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`.